# gsub regex with positive lookbehind capture group

Tags: r, regex

I have strings such as:

```
 "d1 x2 d2x4 5 specimens collected the smallest is 4 x 1 x 3 mm" 
 " stomach x3 d2x4 8 pieces with the largest measuring  4 x 1 x 3 mm"
```

I'd like to add a full stop before the number directly in front of the word 'specimens' to get

```
"d1 x2 d2x4 .5 specimens collected the smallest is 4 x 1 x 3 mm" 
" stomach x3 d2x4 .8 pieces with the largest measuring  4 x 1 x 3 mm"
```

I tried:

```
regstring<-"specimens|pieces"

gsub(paste0("(","(?<=\\d) ",regString,")"),"\\.\\1",inputString,perl=T)
```

which gives me:

```
[1] "d1 x2 d2x4 5. specimens collected the smallest is 4 x 1 x 3 mm mm"
[2] " stomach x3 d2x4 8 .pieces with the largest measuring  4 x 1 x 3 mm"
```

How can I get the full stop before the number instead of after?

Comment: I thought I had captured it

Comment: Similar to the answer below : `sub(sprintf('\\b(\\d+\\s(%s))\\b', regstring), '.\\1', inputString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following expression instead:

```
(\d+)(\s+(?:specimens|pieces)\b)
```

And replace this with

```
".\\1\\2"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xjOG1K/1).

---

In `R` this could be

```
strings <- c("d1 x2 d2x4 5 specimens collected the smallest is 4 x 1 x 3 mm",
            " stomach x3 d2x4 8 pieces with the largest measuring  4 x 1 x 3 mm")
            
strings <- gsub("(\\d+)(\\s+(?:specimens|pieces)\\b)", ".\\1\\2", strings, perl = TRUE)
strings
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Kwek29).

Comment: That's embarrassing. I overcomplicated it. Thanks

Comment: Note you do not even need the `\b` at the start. To match `specimens` as a whole word, better move `\b` to the end, i.e. `(\d+)(\s+(?:specimens|pieces)\b)`